# Partial derivatives of Internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics

If we look at fundamental thermodynamic equation we see that
$$dU=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)dS+\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)dV.$$
We call $\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)$ as temperature. But we call $\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)$ as **negative pressure of the gas**. Why is $\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)$ negative? Is there any good way to resolve if intensive/extensive variables have "negative" relation?

Comment: Short answer: If you have gas in an adiabatic container and you compress it, you're doing work on it and its energy increases: since $dV < 0$, $\partial U / \partial V < 0$.